# Will EF code with AutoMapper's ProjectTo generate efficient SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

The following code (.Net Core 3.0) reads the database table and uses AutoMapper to get a few columns from the table.

```
var employees = await _context.Employees // Employee table has a lot of columns
    .ProjectTo<EmployeeLookupDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider) // EmployeeLookupDto only has three columns
    .OrderBy(e => e.Name)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Will it read all the columns of the database table to memory and then map the data to the three properties `EmployeeLookupDto` class? Or it will actually generate an SQL with select clause of three columns?

Comment: Yes, it will generate efficient SQL. See [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html). You can also turn [SQL logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) on to see for yourself.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: One quick note - your ProjectTo should usually be last in the list, just like in LINQ Select

Comment: Will it affect how the SQL is generated? Or they will have the same expression tree so they will generate the same SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automapper does not generate SQL at all.

Instead, it generates `IQueryable<T>` instances in such a way, that your SQL provider (L2S, EF, or other) will most likely be able to translate into SQL.

And yes, in your example, the resulting SQL will contain only 3 columns and an `Order By` clause.

#### Edit:

Again, AutoMapper does not generate any SQL code.

This part of your code:

```
_context.Employees
    .ProjectTo<EmployeeLookupDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
```

(which is `IQueryable<Employee>`) will be converted into this code:

```
_context.Employees
    .Select(T => new EmployeeLookupDto
    {
         DtoField1 = T.EmployeeField1,
         DtoField2 = T.EmployeeField2,
         ...
    })
```

Which again, is of type `IQueryable`, of your DTO this time. The AutoMapper's work is done at this point.

After that it is all up to your EF Core SQL provider to `OrderBy` this instance into `IOrderedQueryable`, and then actually generating and executing an SQL code in the `ToListAsync` method.

Comment: " AutoMapper does not generate any SQL" needs to be in an `<h1>` tag.